# Folder in Ubuntu Became a File and the other Show Question Mark in Owner/Group

Tags: filesystems, lvm, file-permissions, mdadm, xfs

I encountered a very weird issue, appreciate if someone could help. One of my folder stored in a LVM2 XFS filesystem (mdadm RAID6), silently became a file and a folder showing question mark on both owner and group. All the data on this filesystem are accessed by Win PC via samba all the time. Any idea?

The server information:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- LVM version:     2.02.98(2) (2012-10-15)
- Library version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)
- Driver version:  4.27.0
- mdadm version 1.2
- xfsprogs/trusty-updates 3.1.9ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from:
  3.1.9ubuntu2]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check the filesystem for errors.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, do you mean run the fsck?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @MichaelHampton AFAIK, don't simply run fsck. So I did a search and comes up with this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47953/can-i-run-fsck-or-e2fsck-when-linux-file-system-is-mounted#:~:text=No.,disk%20and%2For%20data%20corruption. Would that actually create more problems?

Comment: Yes, you can't run fsck while the system is mounted. You have to take it down.

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming that. Btw, is that the only option? I probably can only do it a few months later, couldn't simply take the file system offline as there are many users and files on it. So finding an alternative solution would be a better choice to me.

Comment: There is no "alternative" solution to filesystem corruption. You have to fix the filesystem before you can even think about restoring missing data from backup. You can either take the system down and fix it now, or it will take itself down later and be a whole lot more of a nightmare. Of course, if this is happening at all, you may have a hardware problem as well.

Comment: If I do a fsck, would it tells me why the filesystem behave in such a way? Or it may just fix it without letting me know what's happening? I mean, couldn't I identify the issue first before fixing it? Example, perhaps it is captured in one of the log?

Comment: You should have already reviewed the logs!